# JSP unable to detect Bootstrap Spring MVC

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I've been struggling for hours to include the Bootstrap CSS file into my file. My code snippet is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-
1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"> <!--Works fine now, but not with local path -->
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Hello </h1>
            <p> world </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly and the Bootstrap shows up just fine. However, I wish to include the localized files. The moment I change the *`link`* in the head of the code to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">`, The bootstrap disappears.

Just to make sure and convince you that the *bootstrap.css* is indeed there at *resources/bootstrap.css* I included `<%@ include file="/resources/bootstrap.css"%>` at the top of the code and it actually showed me the entire content of the file.

What am I missing? How do I resolve this?

Comment: PS: *NONE* of the existing answers on SO have helped me. There are a couple of questions asking about the same thing but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this project structure (I suggest trying this,because resource folder content is not used for static web contentnt ):

```
|_webapp
       |_css
             |_bootstrap.css
```

you can load the css by

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Inside webapps, resources->styles->bootstrap.css

Comment: And have you checked in browsers developer options-sources-your_app if this bootstrapp file exists?!